# Difficulty outputting multiple findings from regex pattern

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I have created a get request that returns a webpage response body. I am trying to use regex to match all instances of name="valuehere" and return all instances of "valuehere".

I have managed to grep the response body so that I am returning the following data.

"name=\"firstparameter\"", "name=\secondparameter\"", "name=\"thirdparameter\"", "name=\"fourthparameter\""

The regex is working correctly as the following code allows me to print the first parameter it finds multiple times.

```
response = request.response             #gets the full response body of a page and saves to response
puts response.code                      # prints the http response code
parameters = response.body.split(" ").grep(/name=/)            #split the response into an array and grep for anything with name=
parameters.each do |x| 
    x = parameters.to_s.match(/(?<=\\\").*?(?=\\")/i)          #converts array to string and performs regex match()
    puts x
end
```

The problem is that I want to return the value of name="valuehere" for each instance as opposed to just the first one.

The grep method cannot be used in the each method apparently and I have also tried the following:

```
parameters.each do |x| 
    puts x.match(/(?<=\\\").*?(?=\\")/i)          #converts array to string and performs regex match()
```

I believe the problem is with how I am outputting the results from the regex search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `scan` instead of match. 
Scan will return all matches

#### Update 1

```
input_str = %Q["name=\"firstparameter\"", "name=\"secondparameter\"", "name=\"thirdparameter\"", "name=\"fourthparameter\""]
puts "\n"

input_str.split(",").each do |x|
  puts x.split('"').last
  puts "\n"
end
```

```
Output :::::::
$ ruby reg.rb

firstparameter

secondparameter

thirdparameter

fourthparameter
```

Comment: When I use scan the results change. My output is no longer "parameter1", it actually seems to output the data that I am trying to remove with regex.

\"name=", "value1",

Comment: The output I am getting with match is:
Value1
Value1
Value1

The output I am getting with scan is 
value1
", "name=
value1
", "name=
value1

Comment: I've added code in the answer above. Is that what you are expecting ?

Comment: Thanks - This pointed me in the correct direction. Working code
```
parameters = response.body
parameters.split(" ").grep(/name=/).each do |x|
   x.split(",").each do |x|
  puts x.split('"').last
end
end
```